# Can I run Android 4 in a Galaxy Tab 7.1 which current firmware is version 2.3.4?

Tags: android, galaxy-tab

It is a Sprint Galaxy Tab 7".
Model: SPH-P100
firmware: 2.3.4
Kernel: 2.6.35.7

I'm new to android. I want to take this device to start some development on it :)

I'm not sure if I can upgrade it... also no idea how to do it?

any recommendation would be great!
Thanks,

Comment: Stackoverflow is a programming Q/A site, your question is better suited for a site like http://android.stackexchange.com/ or XDA-forums.com

Answer (score 0):

official firmware is unlikely to be.
may be you find custom firmware with 4.0 for your device.
[look this theme](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1383942)